# MongoDB 2.4.10: BSONElement: bad type 67

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('count', u'feedarticles'), 
('fields',    {'_id': 0, 'summary': 1, 'link': 1, 'title': 1}), ('query', 
{'$and': [{'published_parsed': {'$gte': '2014-08-15'}}, 
{'skip': False}, {'title': {'$ne': ''}}]})]) 
failed: 10320 BSONElement: bad type 67
```

I've had the same code scraping RSS feeds and pulling it into mongodb for over a year now (with the only exception of adding new feeds to pull) and now all of a sudden I get this "BSONElement: bad type 67" and have to run a repair on the database to fix it. I can still keep saving data into mongodb, but I just cant query it, at least using python/pymongo.

How can I figure out whats causing this all of a sudden.

Answer (score 0):

apparently I was out of hard drive space and the repair freed up space and allowed me to continue. I still had some corrupt data that even a repair couldn't fix.